# How to call a custom widget in a single.php page of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I want a custom widget to show only inside the post details view page. The concept is that I want to first check the category of the post then next if that category is matched that what I want, it will show that above mentioned custom widget in the sidebar. That widget will be dynamic in nature in the sense that when I wish to show the details of that post the widget will come in that post details page and will hold some data from that post, suppose to say feature image of the post and custom field values of that post. Please give me some solution.

Comment: I have a category review and some article are posted in that category. Now in one of the post details page I want to show a specific widget extra with other sidebar widgets. This widget will have some data regarding the current post.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php the_widget( $widget ); ?>
```

add this anywhere in your template $widget is name of your widget

[THE WIDGET](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget)

Comment: But this will show in all of the post pages. But here I want also a category filtering concept so that this widget will only be visible if when the current post match my condition which I will give.

Comment: i just told you method to add widget in templates, ofcourse you will have to run this under soon condition for example `if(your condition here) {the_widget( $widget );}`

Comment: Ok.Can you give an idea that how can I show some data from that post to that widget.Lets say feature image and some custom field values from that current post

Answer (score 0):

You could hide that widget with CSS, and show it only in that one page. Some pages have custom css classes. for example:

```
.widget-area{display:none;}
.woocommerce-checkout .widget-area{display:block!important;}
```